# Cannot get the Value after parse the Json in C#

Tags: c#, json, parsing

I have a Json String which is follows.

```
{
"jkName": "This is Default Name",
"jkDate": "03-26-2021",
"jkAddress": "3rd Floor MPZ.",
"jkGadget": [{
        "value": "Ipad"
    },
    {
        "value": "Ipod"
    }

],
"jkFood": "Kadala curry"}
```

And i am going to parse this Json string and loop through it using the below c# code.

```
JObject rss = JObject.Parse(DefaultJson);

            foreach (var item in rss)
            {
                var abc = item;
            }
```

When i put "item.key" in the first loop then i got "jkName". This is good. But in the case of "item.Value" then i got error. i have attached the image in the below link.

[Please Click here to see the error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9Nx1.png)

How can i get the Value, means in the first loop when i go for value i need to get "This is Default Name" regarding with this example.

Comment: Why not deserialise to a class so you can navigate it's properties ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code (mine is ok):

```
Newtonsoft.Json.LinqJObject rss = Newtonsoft.Json.LinqJObject.Parse("{\"jkName\": \"This is Default Name\",\"jkDate\": \"03-26-2021\",\"jkAddress\": \"3rd Floor MPZ.\",\"jkGadget\": [{\"value\": \"Ipad\"},{\"value\": \"Ipod\"}],\"jkFood\": \"Kadala curry\"}");

        foreach (var item in rss)
        {
            var abc = item.Value;
            Console.WriteLine(abc);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could model your JSON as classes:

```
public class JkGadget
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string JkName { get; set; }
    public string JkDate { get; set; }
    public string JkAddress { get; set; }
    public List<JkGadget> JkGadget { get; set; }
    public string JkFood { get; set; }
}
```

Then deserialize using [`Json.NET`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) and extract the property you want:

```
var json = "{\"jkName\": \"This is Default Name\",\"jkDate\": \"03-26-2021\",\"jkAddress\": \"3rd Floor MPZ.\",\"jkGadget\": [{\"value\": \"Ipad\"},{\"value\": \"Ipod\"}],\"jkFood\": \"Kadala curry\"}";

var deserializedJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);

var item = deserializedJson.JkName;

Console.WriteLine(item);
// This is Default Name
```

Answer (score 0):

I will use Simple object when the Json allow it.
`[JsonProperty("jkName")]` Allow me to map poorly named property to meaningfull one.

```
public partial class RootObject
{
    [JsonProperty("jkName")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("jkDate")]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("jkAddress")]
    public string Address { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("jkGadget")]
    public List<Gadget> Gadgets { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("jkFood")]
    public string Food { get; set; }
}

public partial class Gadget
{
    [JsonProperty("value")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then the deserialisation is a simple :

```
var result =  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
```

And to access the value :

```
Console.WriteLine(result.Name);
foreach(var stuff in result.Gadgets){
    Console.WriteLine(stuff.Name);
}
```

[Live demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/HCbPNE)